# Change marker position after geolocation?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to change the marker position after getting the geolocation from the browser. I'm guessing that the problem is that `my_marker` is out of the function `getLocation`? Everything before the geolocation works perfectly. Can someone help, please?

```
<!-- Map -->
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="location" value="42.6903741,23.3122929" />
<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&callback=initMap&language=en" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        // Init location
        var my_location = $("#location").val().split(",");

        // Init position
        var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location[0], my_location[1]);

        // Init map
        var my_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: my_position,
            zoom: 17
        });

        // Init marker
        var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: my_position,
            map: my_map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Choose location..."
        });

        // Init listener
        google.maps.event.addListener(my_marker, "dragend", function(event) {
            $("#location").val(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
        });

        // Init geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
        }

        function getLocation(my_location) {
            var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location.coords.latitude, my_location.coords.longitude);

            my_marker.setPosition(my_position);

            $("#location").val(my_location.coords.latitude + "," + my_location.coords.longitude);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  To move the marker in your geolocation processing (when you know the current location), you need to have it available in the scope of the geolocation callback function.  Move the geolocation function inside your `initMap` function.

```
function initMap() {
  // Init location
  var my_location = $("#location").val().split(",");

  // Init position
  var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location[0], my_location[1]);

  // Init map
  var my_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: my_position,
    zoom: 17
  });

  // Init marker
  var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: my_position,
    map: my_map,
    draggable: true,
    title: "Choose location..."
  });

  // Init listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(my_marker, "dragend", function(event) {
    $("#location").val(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
  });

  // Init geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
  }

  function getLocation(my_location) {
    var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location.coords.latitude, my_location.coords.longitude);

    my_marker.setPosition(my_position);
    my_map.setCenter(my_position);

    $("#location").val(my_location.coords.latitude + "," + my_location.coords.longitude);
  }
} // end of initMap
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w2c0smen/1/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
<!-- Map -->
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
<input id="location" value="42.6903741,23.3122929" />
<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infoWindow;

  function initMap() {
    // Init location
    var my_location = $("#location").val().split(",");

    // Init position
    var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location[0], my_location[1]);

    // Init map
    var my_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: my_position,
      zoom: 17
    });

    // Init marker
    my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: my_position,
      map: my_map,
      draggable: true,
      title: "Choose location..."
    });

    // Init listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(my_marker, "dragend", function(event) {
      $("#location").val(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    // Init geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation,
        function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, my_map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, my_map.getCenter());
    };

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(my_map);
    }

    function getLocation(my_location) {
      var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(my_location.coords.latitude, my_location.coords.longitude);

      my_marker.setPosition(my_position);
      my_map.setCenter(my_position);

      $("#location").val(my_location.coords.latitude + "," + my_location.coords.longitude);
    }
  }
</script>
```